# Spark dataframe from dictionary

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create a spark dataframe from a dictionary which has data in the format

```
{'33_45677': 0, '45_3233': 25, '56_4599': 43524} .. etc.
```

```
dict_pairs={'33_45677': 0, '45_3233': 25, '56_4599': 43524}
df=spark.createDataFrame(data=dict_pairs)
```

It throws:

> TypeError: can not infer schema for type: <class 'str'>

Is it because of the underscore in the keys of the dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose dict using square braces '[]'. Its not because of _ in your keys.

```
dict_pairs={'33_45677': 0, '45_3233': 25, '56_4599': 43524}
df=spark.createDataFrame(data=[dict_pairs])
df.show()
```

or

```
dict_pairs=[{'33_45677': 0, '45_3233': 25, '56_4599': 43524}]
df=spark.createDataFrame(data=dict_pairs)
df.show()
```

[image]